# Android App Google Play Services Battery Drain

Tags: android, google-play-services, battery

When using Google Play services API for location and In App Billing request, does the associated Battery/CPU/Wifi/Network usage show up under battery stats under Google Play Services or under the App's Name ?

To my experience OS always shows usage under the associated app's name.

However I have a user claiming that my app causes Google Play Services battery drain with 8-10% on his Nexus 6P when my app does not even show up on his battery stats at all.

Is this somehow possible ?

Comment: I think you can try to `less sync` data from background and disconnect google play services when user are not using your app on onStop();

Comment: That's being done in code already, all objects are properly disposed.

Comment: @AlexVPerl, did you finally figure out what the issue was? My app started to get the exact same issue.. I don't find any way to go about this..